# Convergence of the series $\sum \frac{\sqrt{n+1}-\sqrt{n}}{n^x}$

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, analysis, dirichlet-series

Could you help me to understand for which $x$ this series converge  $\displaystyle\sum \frac{\sqrt{n+1}-\sqrt{n}}{n^x}$?

Comment: Note that $\sqrt{n+1}-\sqrt{n}=\frac{1}{\sqrt{n+1}+\sqrt{n}}\sim\frac{1}{\sqrt{n}+\sqrt{n}}=       \frac{1}{2\sqrt{n}}$

Comment: So that would make $x>\frac{1}{2}$, given the fact that $\displaystyle\sum_{n=1}^\infty n^{-s}$ converges for $s>1$?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Note that $$\frac{\sqrt{n+1}-\sqrt{n}}{n^x}=\frac{\sqrt{n+1}-\sqrt{n}}{n^x}\cdot\frac{\sqrt{n+1}+\sqrt{n}}{\sqrt{n+1}+\sqrt{n}}=\frac{1}{n^x(\sqrt{n+1}+\sqrt{n})}.$$

If $x>1/2$, then 
$$\frac{\sqrt{n+1}-\sqrt{n}}{n^x}=\frac{1}{n^x(\sqrt{n+1}+\sqrt{n})}\leq\frac{1}{n^x(2\sqrt{n})}=\frac{1}{2n^{x+\frac{1}{2}}}.$$
Since $\displaystyle\sum\frac{1}{2n^{x+\frac{1}{2}}}$ converges when $x>1/2$ (see [p-series](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Harmonic_series_%28mathematics%29#P-series)), by [comparison test](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_test), $\displaystyle\sum\frac{\sqrt{n+1}-\sqrt{n}}{n^x}$ converges.

On the other hand, if $x\le 1/2$,
$$\frac{\sqrt{n+1}-\sqrt{n}}{n^x}=\frac{1}{n^x(\sqrt{n+1}+\sqrt{n})}\geq\frac{1}{n^x(\sqrt{n})}=\frac{1}{n^{x+\frac{1}{2}}}\geq\frac{1}{n}.$$
Since the [harmonic series](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Harmonic_series_%28mathematics%29) diverges, by comparison test again, $\displaystyle\sum\frac{\sqrt{n+1}-\sqrt{n}}{n^x}$ diverges.

Answer (score 0):

We know that $\displaystyle\sum_{n=1}^\infty n^{-s}$ converges for $s>1$.

As pointed out by Norbert, $\sqrt{n+1}-\sqrt{n}= \frac{1}{\sqrt{n+1}+\sqrt{n}}<\frac{1}{\sqrt{n}+\sqrt{n}}$.

Hence, $\displaystyle\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{\sqrt{n+1}-\sqrt{n}}{n^x}<\displaystyle\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{1}{2\times{n^{\frac{1}{2}+x}}}$.

hence, for convergence, we must have the exponent of n $>1$. Hence, we must have $x>\frac{1}{2}$.

Comment: What if $ x \le \frac 12$? You've used inequalities, and we don't know what happens if $x \le \frac 12$. ;)

Comment: For $x=1/2$, it becomes Harmonic series, which we know to be divergent. For $x\le (1/2)$, by comparison test, we can see that the series diverges since Harmonic series diverges.